# Fourier coefficient of $f \in L^1([a,b])$

Tags: real-analysis

If $f \in L^1([- \pi , \pi])$, by definition, the Fourier coefficients of $f$ are given by
$$
c_k = \frac{1}{2 \pi} \int_{- \pi}^{\pi} f(t) e^{- i k t} \, dt
$$
for all $k \in \mathbb{Z}$. Is there any definition for Fourier coefficients of $g \in L^1([a , b])$?

Comment: See the deduction of the coefficients formula and you may be able to deduce it by yourself. The last part of http://mathworld.wolfram.com/FourierSeries.html is a good place to start. If you need, I can deduce them for you in a future answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are other conventions, but one is that, with $L = b-a$, the Fourier coefficients of $g$ are

$$ c_k = \frac{1}{L} \int_a^b g(t) e^{-2\pi i k t/L}\; dt $$

Comment: Ok thank you very much.

Comment: Do you know if Parseval equality is true in this case too?

Comment: Yes, in the form $$\sum_{k=-\infty}^\infty |c_k|^2 = \frac{1}{L} \int_a^b |g(t)|^2\; dt$$
or for $f$ with Fourier coefficients $c_k$ and $g$ with Fourier coefficients $d_k$, 
$$ \sum_{k=-\infty}^\infty c_k \overline{d_k} = \frac{1}{L} \int_a^b f(t) \overline{g(t)} \; dt$$

Comment: OK thank you very much.